# Using awk to parse a string from a file

Tags: arrays, unix, awk

I'm still learning Unix and I'm having issues understanding the following line of code.

```
echo "$lines" | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[3],a[2],a[1]}'
```

I don't understand what is happening with the array a in the line of code above. Is it declaring the array and setting it equal to the string it's parsing? If it is declaring the array a, then, why can't I print out the results later on in the code?

```
echo "${a[1]}"
```

The line above prints an empty line and not what has been stored in the array a when the string was parsed. I know there is always something in the string that needs to be parsed and when I call the array a[1] I know that I'm in inside the scope. I just don't see/understand what is happening with the array a that prevents me from printing it out later on in the code.

Comment: The `awk` array `a` is only available in the `awk` script; it is not a part of the shell.  That's why you can't access it in the `echo` command later.

Comment: Then how would I save the array to a variable that I can use? Would it be something like this: VAR=($(echo "$lines" | awk '{split($0,a,":")}'))

Comment: Yes (now your comment has been updated to include some code).  You might want to use: `a=( $(echo "$lines" | awk '{ … }') )` to do a shell array assignment.  However, that would process all lines into a single shell array.  You'd have to decide whether that's OK.  It would also lose any spaces in the array elements (so if one of the lines contained `aa bb:cc dd:ee ff gg`, you'd get 7 shell array elements from the 3 Awk array elements).  You'll have to judge whether that's a problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is printing a line for each line of input. If you dont have get output, my first guess would be, that you don't have input.

Given an input of:

```
lines="ab:cd:ef
ij:kl:m"
```

the output is:

```
ef cd ab
m kl ij
```

`awk` is executing the commands (which is everything in between the single quotes) for each line of input. First splitting the input line `$0` at each `:` into an array `a`, then printing the first three elements in reverse order.

If you try to access an array element in the shell, what `echo` suggests, then you are too late. The array exists within awk and is gone when awk has finished.